# How to specify the order of labels in the color legend of Vega?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have the following definition which draws lines from two groups of data: A and B. When using the `"color"` property in `"encoding"`, Vega will create a legend for the colors and will display the groups in alphabetical order by default. How can I specify the that I want B to appear before A in the legend?

More generally, I want to be able to sort labels in any order, not just descending or ascending order.

[See the chart here.](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAHvCAIwgA0IA5gE4D2aADsQEIUjLobwAMAdACYAvuULEB7Wg2ZwQbSp0y8%20AFhFjZAZkn0mrdou5x%20m9SCKyylKXtkBBA6iXG%20JMxZATrumSAcKnIx53Ym1vaWJ-DkDlYQBdERAAWwgaAGtiFABLADtuSgwcgGM6MFyqeA1QADMsjBQwYiJEgE9KkFr6xtlDdigWxiMQAEc0CByoLJhJxG5EkpQ6GnbOhuIbZiEtoA)

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x":"1", "group": "B", "value":0.2},
      {"x":"2", "group": "B", "value":0.4},
      {"x":"3", "group": "B", "value":0.3},
      {"x":"1", "group": "A", "value":0.1},
      {"x":"2", "group": "A", "value":0},
      {"x":"3", "group": "A", "value":0.2}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "group"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a sort to the encoding.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": "1", "group": "B", "value": 0.2},
      {"x": "2", "group": "B", "value": 0.4},
      {"x": "3", "group": "B", "value": 0.3},
      {"x": "1", "group": "A", "value": 0.1},
      {"x": "2", "group": "A", "value": 0},
      {"x": "3", "group": "A", "value": 0.2}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "group", "sort": "descending"}
  }

}
```

You can also add a custom sort as follows:

```
"sort": ["B", "A", "C"]
```

Comment: More generally, suppose I have groups A, B and C and want the specific order C, A, B, how could I do? Is there a way to give a custom sort function?

Comment: "sort": ["C", "A", "B"]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I suggest you add it to you answer because as simple as it looks, this was very hard to find for me.